Cannot install scipy due to meson-python - a-shell on iPad 4 Pro
Using a-shell on iPad Pro 4. Failed to pip install scipy. I am not sure what’s the problem.
I tried to install/upgrade meson-python and pyproject.toml, but it seems that the package is already up to date. A-shell comes with pandas and numpy pre installed. I tried to upgrade numpy and I got the same error message.
Finally, I tried to install older versions of scipy and it keeps failing for similar reasons.
[~]$ pip install scipy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-1.14.0.tar.gz (58.6 MB)
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [2 lines of output]
  
  meson-python: error: Could not find meson version 0.63.3 or newer, found .
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

————————————————————————————————
Following tbrugere’s comment I ran “ pip install scipy --no-build-isolation --verbose”. The error message is now as follows:
    Using cached scipy-1.14.0.tar.gz (58.6 MB)
      Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
      meson-python: error: Could not find meson version 0.63.3 or newer, found .
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      full command: python3  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A7402AB-0D9B-458A-AD0E-4876CA8F4F4F/Library/lib/python3.11/sitepackages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A7402AB-0D9B-458A-AD0E-4876CA8F4F4F/tmp/tmpsgn2hb9n 
      cwd: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A7402AB-0D9B-458A-AD0E-4876CA8F4F4F/tmp/pip-install-edonx9pv/scipy_084964d010b54e1cbbfb9a7154db89a4
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
    error: metadata-generation-failed
    × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
    ╰─> See above for output.
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for details.


The important part of the error message is this
meson-python: error: Could not find meson version 0.63.3 or newer, found .
Which basically means it is not finding meson which is needed for building scipy.
pip install meson

may solve this

Thank you for the reply. I already did that, but it does not solve the issue.

what happens if you try running meson

I get the following message
    -
    ERROR: Must specify at least one directory name.
    WARNING: Running the setup command as `meson [options]` instead of `meson setup [options]` is ambiguous and deprecated.


OK so that means meson installed correctly, but the install script cannot find it. This might be an issue with the build isolation in pip. Can you try the pip command with --no-build-isolation ? also add --verbose for better error messages

Sorry I think I misunderstood your question. I updated the error message in the main text. I still get the same error message, but with more details.

Added the extra details to the main message.
